# Batch script how to compare array of strings

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

I have array like `a[0]= ABC , a[1]=ABC , a[2]=ABC` and I want to compare it using :

```
if  %a[0]%==%a[1]%=%a[2]% ( echo Equal)
```

Comparing three is not working but comparing two works fine.

```
if  %a[0]%==%a[1]% ( echo Equal)
```

any suggestion, please ?

Comment: Where in the help file for the `IF` command did you read that you could use syntax like that for the `IF` command?

Comment: Related: [Batch-file "and if" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33708207)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check multiple (pseudo-)array elements for equality, you could try this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FLAG=#"   & rem // (flag that is going to be cleared in case of an encountered inequality)
set /A "MAX=9" & rem // (greatest array index number to be included in the comparison loop)
for /L %%I in (1,1,%MAX%) do if not "!a[0]!"=="!a[%%I]!" set "FLAG="
if defined FLAG echo All array elements from index 0 to %MAX% are equal.
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested IF command will do what you want.

```
if  "%a[0]%"=="%a[1]%" if "%a[1]%"=="%a[2]%" echo Equal
```

Another simple solution for comparing 3 numbers to see if they are all the same.

```
if "%a[1]%,%a[2]%,%a[3]%"=="%a[2]%,%a[3]%,%a[1]%" echo All same
```

Comment: Hey this works.. but if I have a arry of 10 strings.. How can I compare them via for loop?

Comment: @ty139, what about extending that command line accordingly...?